# Order to upgrade kubernetes CRD and CR

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Consider this:

1. Deploy an ansible operator which will watch a CRD A
2. Create CR B with Kind A
3. bunch of deployments/pods get started for CR B.

Now I need to upgrade the operator, CRD, and CR. What will be the correct order to apply new resource to reduce the broken time of existing deployments/pods?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the operator implementations. For instance, if the operator created to considers the version compatibility between old and new CRD, and the operator may make existing pods keep running. Or it can implement the operator make running pod restart with rolling updates. It's case by case, so you check the specification of the operator upgrade process first.